# stop called in an invalid state: 1

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to build a call recorder in android. I am using the `MediaRecorder` Class:
When My App reaches the following line: `recorder.stop()` I get the following error:

```
stop called in an invalid state: 1
```

What causes that problem?

Thanks in advance,

kobi

Comment: Hi Kobi, It would help if you'd post the relevant code snippet

Answer (score 3):

From the MediaRecorder documents page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Looking at the state diagram given, you can only call `stop()` when the `MediaRecorder` is in the state `Recording`

Hard to tell what you are doing wrong without code, but you have to be in the wrong state to call `stop()`.

Comment: I've got the same problem and I've set the maximum duration to ten seconds, which could well mean it's *stopped* recording, but I need a way to find that out.  Is there a method you can call to determine if you're in a recording state?

Comment: Looks like it is still an open issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=800

I think you just have to keep track of the state yourself by using the listeners it provides. :/

Comment: @AndrewWyld you can't query the state directly, but you can use a MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener which tells you if the video reached a time or size limit