# android - MediaRecorder throws illegalstateexception

Tags: android, mediarecorder, illegalstateexception

I am trying to develop a simple android audio recorder.Everything builds fine and it also runs fine on the android device. It seems like i can start the recording but when i want to stop it throws a IllegalStateException. I can't find the mistake. Here is the code:

```
public class VoiceRecorder {
MediaRecorder recorder= new MediaRecorder();
static Context cont;

public void startRecord(Context context) throws IllegalStateException, IOException{
    cont = context;

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    recorder.setOutputFile(cont.getFilesDir()+"/recordings.3gp"); 
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();  

 }  
public void stopRecording(Context context) {
    cont = context;
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    File file = new File (cont.getFilesDir()+"/recordings.3gp");
    UploadFile.uploadFile("recordings.3gp", file);
    recorder = null;
 }
}
```

I want to trigger it with:

VoiceRecorder vr = new VoiceRecorder();

vr.startRecord(cont);

vr.stopRecording(cont);

when calling start Logcat says: (what should be ok)

```
09-06 22:56:42.830: D/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): audpre_index = 0, tx_iir_index = 0
09-06 22:56:42.840: D/HTC Acoustic(123): msm72xx_enable_audpre: 0x0000
09-06 22:56:42.850: I/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): Routing audio to Speakerphone
09-06 22:56:42.850: D/HTC Acoustic(123): msm72xx_enable_audpp: 0x0001
09-06 22:56:42.850: I/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): Routing audio to Speakerphone
09-06 22:56:42.860: D/HTC Acoustic(123): msm72xx_enable_audpp: 0x0001
09-06 22:56:42.870: D/AudioFlinger(123): setParameters(): io 3, keyvalue routing=262144;vr_mode=0, tid 156, calling tid 123
09-06 22:56:42.870: I/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): Routing audio to Speakerphone
09-06 22:56:42.880: D/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): audpre_index = 0, tx_iir_index = 0
09-06 22:56:42.880: D/HTC Acoustic(123): msm72xx_enable_audpre: 0x0000
09-06 22:56:42.880: I/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): do input routing device 40000
09-06 22:56:42.880: I/AudioHardwareMSM72XX(123): Routing audio to Speakerphone
09-06 22:56:42.890: D/HTC Acoustic(123): msm72xx_enable_audpp: 0x0001
```

But when i call stop:

```
09-06 22:59:52.440: E/MediaRecorder(1069): stop called in an invalid state: 1
09-06 22:59:52.440: W/System.err(1069): java.lang.IllegalStateException
09-06 22:59:52.460: W/System.err(1069):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
09-06 22:59:52.460: W/System.err(1069):     at de.spyapp.VoiceRecorder.stopRecording(VoiceRecorder.java:33)
09-06 22:59:52.460: W/System.err(1069):     at de.spyapp.CheckCMD.checkCMD(CheckCMD.java:30)
09-06 22:59:52.460: W/System.err(1069):     at de.spyapp.AppActivity$2.run(AppActivity.java:44)
09-06 22:59:52.460: W/System.err(1069):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't in stop, but in start. It doesn't start correctly, that's why you can't stop it later.

Check couple of things:
a) That you added persmission android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

b) That you write to SD card (I am not sure it's requirement, but I believe I had problem writing to internal memory). You will need permission to write to SD card.

c) Also, try to set onErrorListener
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)

d) Try to reset() MediaPlayer before any other calls
I would recommend to read this article 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States
Android's MediaRecorder states is the nightmare.

Comment: all permissions are ok. i tried changing to sd card and did a reset at beginning of startrecording method. Now logcat tells me sth new on .start():

09-06 23:34:20.310: D/audio_input(123): DoStop: X

09-06 23:34:20.330: D/audio_input(123): DoReset: E

09-06 23:34:20.340: D/audio_input(123): DoReset: X

09-06 23:34:20.340: E/audio_input(123): unsupported parameter: 
x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value

09-06 23:34:20.340: E/audio_input(123): VerifyAndSetParameter failed

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that error is thrown when you call stop() from an invalid state.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()

The activity cycle for the recorder also seems to indicate you need to prepare() it before you can start recording - are you doing that?  stop() isn't a valid command unless the recorder is at least prepared.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram

If you are, maybe it takes a moment for the recorder to actually settle in a valid state before you can later call stop().  You are calling it *immediately* after start() so maybe something is happening there.

Comment: Not allowed to post more than two hyperlinks.  Some further reading: 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852852/stop-called-in-an-invalid-state-1
 - http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/

Comment: hmm i called the prepare before start and i'm waiting like 20sec untill i call the stop

Comment: This answer is referencing `MediaPlayer` but the OP is asking about `MediaRecorder`